# Preg_replace/str_replace() for changing `&lt;` and `&gt;` instances to `<` and `>` respectively

Tags: preg-replace, str-replace

One of our pages pulls content from a database table using the following code:

`<?php echo $project['description']; ?>`

What I need is for all `&lt;` and `&gt;` instances to be replaced with `<` and `>` respectively. Can you help modify the above code to include a `preg_replace` statement (or `str_replace()`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($project['description']); ?>
```

Should get you what you need.

If you are ONLY looking to decode those, though, then:

```
<?php echo str_replace("&lt;","<",str_replace("&gt;",">",$project['description'])); ?>
```

And preg_replace should look like this:

```
<?php echo preg_replace(&lt;,"<",preg_replace(&gt;,">",$project['description'])); ?>
```

I'm pretty sure the `&` isn't a special character, but if it does cause you issues, put a `\` before it.

Comment: @JoeW Does it look exactly like what is written here, or is there more on that line for some other stuff that needed done?

Comment: I've gone for the second option which does the job perfectly - thanks a lot.