# Why does FCKeditor change `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;` when editing?

Tags: php, parsing, fckeditor

**FCKeditor v2.6.6** alters input code containing `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively causing errors. Is there any way I can configure FCKeditor to parse these characters correctly to avoid them being entered into our database and incorrectly rendered when output in the PHP file?

I have changed the ProcessHTMLEntities to true `FCKConfig.ProcessHTMLEntities = true` in fckconfig.js but no change. I also have preg_replace running on the final output pages to try an eliminate this, but FCKeditor seems to manage to duplicate its content and the output is not pretty (as per my other question here: [Preg_replace/str_replace() for changing `&lt;` and `&gt;` instances to `<` and `>` respectively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294270/preg-replace-str-replace-for-changing-lt-and-gt-instances-to-and/9294401#9294401)). I'm hoping there is some code I can add to that file to correct this.

Comment: Have you considered switching to the newer CKEditor? I found it much more reliable and generally nicer to use.

Comment: We've definitely considered it yes, but we have a live site and I don't think there's a simple way to 'upgrade' without rewriting the pages it is situated in our end.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Configuration/Configuration_Options/ProcessHTMLEntities) has this to say:

> **ProcessHTMLEntities**
>
> Specifies that the editor must convert all special characters
> available in the text to their relative HTML entities, as defined by
> the W3C standards. It is set to true by default.

Try using `FCKConfig.ProcessHTMLEntities = false` instead.

Comment: On further testing it is showing it's old errors again. No idea how to sort this.